# Why we call shiv shanker and why never call shanker shiv?

Tags: scripture

First of all shiv is supreme father paramathma living in the supreme abode and shanker is a human( not even a diety ) In his body shiva come as ekvyapi and give studies of creation destruction and sustainence from old world to new world. Only shanker is called deva deva mahadeva . We also have three murthies which is shanker parvathy or lakshmi narayana ( not just narayana but satya narayana. and brahma ( he is not worshiped in this trhee murthies.